# How to POST to WebAPI via C# Win8 Metro CP

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am using the consumer preview of Windows 8 using a xaml client with C# (NOT javascript).

Syntax and method overloads change with each iteration of a library, if you are helping me out, (which I thank you for in advance) please make sure you are giving advice on the current versions.

Could someone please show me how to use `HttpClient` to POST this POCO to my ASP.NET Web API web service using C#?  I am able to GET my POCO classes from my Web API, but I am a little unclear on the other side of the coin.

```
class Person
{
    string Fname {get; set;}
    string Lame {get; set;}
    DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: In the same boat, and what more [HttpContentExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions(v=vs.108).aspx) is not available in Metro app.